# Parse a JSON array with Moment.js in a subscribe-function

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, momentjs

I got multiple `time` items in a `data` JSON array, which I want to parse and format with **Moment.js** and store them into the `this.appointmentTimes` array, which I can easily access on my view with `{{appointmentTime.time}}`.

**This is my JSON:**

```
[
  { "time":"2018-10-22T14:30:00+0200", "slotsAvailable":1 },
  { "time":"2018-10-22T14:45:00+0200", "slotsAvailable":1 },
  { "time":"2018-10-22T15:00:00+0200", "slotsAvailable":1 }
]
```

---

**After page refresh I get this error:**

```
ERROR in src/app/pages/booking/form/booking.component.ts(75,9): error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'object[]'.
src/app/pages/booking/form/booking.component.ts(76,22): error TS2345: Argument of type 'object[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

---

**This is my corresponding function which will be executed through my view.**

```
private appointmentLocations: Array<object> = [];
private appointmentTypes: Array<object> = [];
private appointmentTimes: Array<object> = [];

onChangeTypeId(TypeId) {
    console.log(TypeId);
    this.selectedAppointmentTypeId = TypeId;
    this.apiService
      .getAppointmentTimesById(
        this.selectedAppointmentTypeId,
        this.selectedAppointmentLocation,
        this.selectedDatePicker
      )
      .subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
        /*this.appointmentTimes = data; */
        this.appointmentTimes = JSON.stringify(
          JSON.parse(data).map(function(data) {
            var pattern = 'HH:mm';
            data = moment(data.time).format(pattern);
            return data;
          })
        );
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

`.map(response => response.json())` before you subscribe because the response is string, not JSON.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately, but I'm getting another error, that "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'".

Comment: You need to import map. Not sure what version you're using, but please try this and let me know if it works: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; `

Comment: if that doens't work, then try `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

Comment: Don't import `add` packages. Use `pipe(map())` insteed.

Comment: This still doesn't work: .subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
        this.appointmentTimes = JSON.stringify(
          JSON.parse(data).pipe(
            map(function(data) {
              var pattern = 'HH:mm';
              data = moment(data.time).format(pattern);
              return data;
            })
          )
        );